# How can I use firebase MFA for adding extra layer of auth for a specific feature?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to be able to add an extra layer of security when a user tries to use a special feature, basically following firebase docs for MFA: `Require adding a second factor incrementally when the user wants to access features with increased security requirements`

However, (and to many, maybe obviously) after the user has been enrolled into MFA,
it seems to always ask the user for the MFA during login as well.
Is it possible to only ask for it during a specific user action, like click of a button?